Can we have separate color of command and output text in terminal?
with Ubuntu 24.04
I am lokking for solution ,  is there any way which change the command color separate from its output, although we can customize the color but it applies both command and its output but I want separate so that command visibaly clear when take screenwhot.
for eg below screenshot both command and its output are in white text
can we do some tweak so that command show  diffrent color


The variables are meant to be used in double quotes. In single quotes, like you have in first two PS1='...' lines, embed the text directly PS1='... \[\033[0;31m\]$(...'

yes. change the quotes but not showing any color to host and username

Changing the quotes is the wrong to do there because of the other things in the prompt, and it's not what I suggested.

At any rate, if PS1="$PS1${LIGHT_RED}" works with your original prompt, then your question is answered. Post a new question if you want to modify other things in your original prompt.

Thanks. asked here
